# NodeJS Express req.body returning empty string object

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I'm fairly new to nodeJS and express. I'm having an issue that I just cannot seem to be able to solve.

This the app.js

```
var express         = require("express"),
    app             = express(),
    mongoose        = require("mongoose"),
    bodyParser      = require("body-parser");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/to_do_app", {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

// MODEL TODO
var todoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
var Todo = mongoose.model("Todo", todoSchema);

// Todo.create({
//     title: "Database To-Do Entry",
// });

// ROUTES
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    Todo.find({}, function(err, todos){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("index", {todos: todos});
        }
    })
});

//CREATE ROUTE
app.post("/", function (req, res){
    Todo.create(req.body.todo, function(err, newToDo){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("added" + newToDo)
        }
        console.log(req.body.todo);
    });
});

// START
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server has started!");
});
```

index.ejs

```
<%- include("partials/header") %>

<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="card bg-dark" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-header text-white">
                    To-Do List
                    <a href="#collapseToDo" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fas fa-plus ml-auto"></i></a>
                </div>

                <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseToDo">
                        <form action="/" method="POST">
                            <input class="list-group-item bg-light rounded-0" name="todo[title]" type="text" placeholder="Enter To-Do">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <% todos.forEach(function(todos){ %>
                    <li class="list-group-item"><%= todos.title %><span><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span></li>
                    <% }) %>
                </ul>
            </div> 
    </div>
</div>

<%- include("partials/footer") %>
```

Everytime I run this code and I try to add something new to the database req.body.todo returns {Title:""}. The string is completely empty. I cannot find a way to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is this line `<input class="list-group-item bg-light rounded-0" name="todo[title]" type="text" placeholder="Enter To-Do">`

Name of the input field is `todo[title]`, but on your server you tried to get the todo title with `req.body.todo`.

I think you need update your ejs file, set name of the input to `todo`:

`<input class="list-group-item bg-light rounded-0" name="todo" type="text" placeholder="Enter To-Do">`

I see you `CREATE ROUTE` does not do anything when a Todo has been created. I think, redirect to the `/` route will be good.

And, if you using `mongoose`, then `Todo.create` requires a object instead of a string, I guest a Todo only need `title` field, then finally route will become:

```
app.post("/", function (req, res){
    Todo.create({title: req.body.todo}, function(err, newToDo){ // object Todo
        if(err){
            console.log(err); // return to error page like res. render('error', {erro})
        } else {
            console.log("added" + newToDo)
            res.redirect('/') // reload the page
        }
        console.log(req.body.todo);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply! I've tried doing what you said but end up with this error:

`MongooseError [ObjectParameterError]: Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got'`

Comment: @YaadMohammad I updated my answer, I update the `Todo.create....` line.

Comment: Thanks! That helped. I also needed to make sure there was a button or input that submitted the entire form. That was the last piece of the puzzle. Thanks!